# Конфликт Borland Delphi7 и Borland C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, активация, c++

Добрый вечер.

В связи со сложившейся ситуацией, мне необходимо работать с **Borland Delphi7** и **Borland C++ Builder**, на одной машине.

Установились они нормально, но при запуске выскакивает ошибка, гласящая о том, что стоит другой продукт от **Borland** и у них не совпадают ключи активации и появляется выбор об изменении его в реестре.

Если заменяю, то перестает работать другой продукт(( Что можете посоветовать в данной ситуации?

З.Ы. Пытался поставить на разные локальные диски, но результат тот же. Спасите меня...

Comment: Купите эти продукты и замучайте службу поддержки :-) Можно наверное посмотреть что за ключи меняются в реестре и менять их соответствующие при запуске нужного продукта.

Comment: @Чад, проблема в том, что обе софтины достигли возраста end of support.

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема редко, но случается с  **Borland Delphi7** и **Borland C++ Builder 6**.

Я в такой ситуации делаю следующее:

1) захожу в реестр в ветку **[HKEY_CURRENT_USER]\Software**

2) удаляю из этой ветки папку **Borland** целиком.

3) запускаю **Delphi** (если просит ключ ввожу).

```
(желательно ключи при генерации брать не первые предложенные)
```

4) Запускаю **С++ Builder** (если просит ключ ввожу).

```
(желательно ключи при генерации брать не первые предложенные)
```

5) закрываю и пробую проверить...

---

надеюсь поможет и вам